# Stripe Webhook Error 500

Tags: php, json, stripe-payments, phpmailer, webhooks

I'm trying to set up a Stripe webhook that sends an email once a 'charge.succeeded' event occurs. I keep getting a generalized 'error 500' when I test the webhook on Stripe. I'm quite new to Stripe and I'm really stuck here.

```
<?php

require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
$mail = new PHPMailer;

require_once('stripe/lib/Stripe.php');
Stripe::setApiKey("XXXYYYZZZ");

// retrieve the request's body and parse it as JSON
$body = @file_get_contents('php://input');
$event_json = json_decode($body);

// for extra security, retrieve from the Stripe API
$event_id = $event_json->id;
$event = Stripe_Event::retrieve($event_id);

// This will send receipts on successful charges
if ($event_json->type == 'charge.succeeded') {

        // This is where we e-mail the invoice.

        $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';                 // Specify main and backup server
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = 'abc@gmail.com';                            // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = 'password!';                           // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted

        $mail->From = 'abc@gmail.com';
        $mail->FromName = 'John Doe';
        $mail->addAddress('email@stanford.edu, John Doe');  // Add a recipient


        $mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters

        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

        $mail->Subject = 'Your webhook works!!!!!';

        $mail->Body    = "The message sent!";


        if(!$mail->send()) {
           echo 'Message could not be sent. Contact us at hello@beerboy.co.';
           echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
           exit;
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: Is Stripe responding with a 500, or is your own server doing that?  I suspect `$body = @file_get_contents('php://input');` is making it unhappy. Have you checked your logs to see where the error is occuring?

Comment: I got this ... Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Stripe_InvalidRequestError' with message 'Could not determine which URL to request: Stripe_Event instance has invalid ID: stripe/lib/Stripe/ApiResource.php:46. I'm not sure if it threw this because there's not an event ID in there because it's supposed to get that fron stripe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this code:

```
// retrieve the request's body and parse it as JSON
$body = @file_get_contents('php://input');
$event_json = json_decode($body);

// for extra security, retrieve from the Stripe API
$event_id = $event_json->id;
$event = Stripe_Event::retrieve($event_id);
```

`$body` is defined using `php://input`, which wants to read from the POST or GET information submitted to *your page*, not to Stripe.  [See here](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php).  Whatever is in POST or GET apparently is invalid JSON or contains an invalid `id`.

So, when you try to `json_decode($body)`, you are trying to json_decode what is in POST or GET, not what you got from Stripe.  `$event_json->id` doesn't exist or is invalid, so `$event_id` doesn't exist or is invalid, so Stripe flips out when you call `Stripe_Event::retrieve($event_id);`.

Try `var_dump($event_json); die();` before you make the `Stripe_Event` call and see what is in your request.

**EDIT:** Make sure you are POSTing (or including the query string) syntactically valid JSON.  In other words, how are your users going to reach this page?  Make sure that wherever they are coming from, the input contains valid JSON and matches your expectations (i.e., has an `id` parameter, etc.).

Comment: I just got "NULL" ... So how might I remedy this? :/

Comment: Well, there you go.  If `$event_json` turns out to be null or invalid, then your next couple of statements are doomed.  You should validate your inputs here and make sure they are non-empty, match the expected syntax, etc.  Note that you *must* have some JSON in GET or POST, or there is no way that your `file_get_contents` will work.  If you are trying to test this page by calling it directly (no GET or POST), you will *always* throw an error.

Comment: I could be wrong about this, but it seems like the request is coming from Stripe and my code here is supposed to just process it. "Webhook data is sent as JSON in the request's body."https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks#receiving-a-webhook

Comment: How are you testing this?  If you aren't sending it any data, or if the data isn't valid JSON with a valid `id` parameter, it won't work.

Comment: @JonathanOsborn IF this answer was helpful would you mind to accept is as "Helpful" ?

Answer (score 1):

For those who are still looking for an answer, remove the '@' sign from the `file_get_contents()` function:

```
`Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_5cgfJ8yqBHE8L6radSAUhoo7");
$input = file_get_contents("php://input");
$event_json = json_decode($input);
var_dump($event_json);
http_response_code(200); // PHP 5.4 or greater`
```

Send a test from the stripe webhooks section for stripe admin. You will get a message "Test webhook sent successfully", click on this to see the response which should be an array of the request object.

Answer (score -1):

You should add this line in the end:

> http_response_code(200); // PHP 5.4 or greater

And before all the `exit;`s